# owl carrousel items with autoWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am trying to use the latest carousel docs to achieve what I need, basically I want to show 3 images in big screens 2 in tablets and 1 in mobile devices, the thing is that i already achieve this before, but 1 of my images got stretched, so i tried to use auto width, the image stopped being stretched, but then occurs another issue my carousel don't display the items that I set in the responsive object, it tries to fit all the container with all my items, what can I do to have the image with a good ratio, and that my images continue being responsive:

Code:

```
<section class="content_section bg_gray border_b_n">
    <div class="content row_spacer clearfix" style="max-width:939px">
      <div class="owl-carousel">
             <div class="item">
                <img src="image1.png" width="112" height="112" alt="client name">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image2.png" width="210" height="40" alt="client name">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image3.png" width="210" height="40" alt="client name">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image4.png" width="210" height="40" alt="client name">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image5.png" width="112" height="112" alt="client name">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image6.png" width="210" height="40" alt="client name">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image7.png" width="112" height="112" alt="client name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

      responsiveClass:true,
      items: 3,
      autoplay: true,
      margin:20,      
      loop:true,
      mouseDrag:false,
      autoWidth:true
    responsive:{
                0: {
            items: 1
        },
        479: {
            items: 1
        },
        768: {
            items: 2
        },
        979: {
            items: 3
        }

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I've got same issue.. Any solution yet?

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
-- Set `max-width:100%` of images